# ASP.NET LINQ Is it possible to do a standard SQL Query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-binding, gridview

I was wondering if it was possible to perform traditional SQL queries using LINQ. I would then like to DataBind the results to a GridView.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you mean you want to write straight SQL, rather than using the LINQ query operators? While I suspect it's possible, I'd be interested to know why you didn't want to use LINQ fully...

Comment: @JonSkeet I realize this isn't the OP's difficulty but I recently had requirements to retrieve a free-form clear text WHERE clause from a backing store and construct a query from it. I had no desire to parse into a LINQ statement so `ExecuteQuery()` came in handy.. I didn't care for the design paradigm but sometimes requirements make us do strange things. :]

Comment: Sometimes using complex querys with multiple joins it is easier to write in sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ExecuteQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use the method `ExecuteQuery` on your DataContext:

```
IEnumerable<YourTable> rows = dataContext.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM YourTable");
```